# Running .NET 3.5 applications on Windows 10 without installing anything or shipping app.config

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have a WPF app that has the following requirements:

1. Has to work in Windows 7 through Windows 10 without installing anything additional to the system

   - i.e. has to work on both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4 frameworks systems
2. It needs to be a single executable, no other configuration files or DLLs present

I was able to get this mostly working by building my app while targeting .NET 3.5 and Costura.Fody. I am then able to get it working on machines that do not have .NET 3.5 installed on it by using the following in the App.Config:

```
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>
```

The problem is, this only works if the app.exe.config is sitting next to the exe which breaks requirement #3.

What alternatives do I have for this? I thought about possibly creating a C++ application that has the EXE and the Config embedded in it and on startup copying the 2 files to a temp folder (if not already there) and executing it from there, but I wasn't sure if there was a better way.

Comment: Creating an additional C++ application instead of simply deploying an additional configuration file? Are you serious?

Comment: that is the requirement that I was given

Comment: Well, then I guess you'll have to embed the .exe and the .config file into some .exe and then extract them on startup. The version of the .NET Framework that an app runs on is determined in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5) order which includes an `App.config`.

Comment: thanks - so my assumption was correct. no other way to do what is required without creating another EXE such as c++ that runs on all windows outside of the .NET framework

Comment: Did you consider moving to .NET Core and ship a [single-file executable](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2019/09/22/single-file-exes-in-net-core/)?

Comment: i did not consider that. I will investigate that and see if that would be a solution - thank you

Comment: On the bright side, if you create a "dropper" program, keep in mind then you don't need `Costura.Fody` embedding. Just zip up your app, add it as a resource to your C program, then unzip at runtime. The "single file application" for .NET Core is essentially doing the same thing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#single-file-executables

Comment: 12 years ago... .NET Framework 3.5. Windows XP SP2. Sweet memories. :)

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file is required for a .NET Framework application that is compiled against the .NET Framework 3.5 to run on the .NET Framework 4 as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5).

Your best option is probably to move to .NET Core and deploy your app as a [single-file executable](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2019/09/22/single-file-exes-in-net-core/).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - I am able to create a self-extracting application using IExpress which will store the 2 files (exe and config) into the temp folder then launch the exe. This seems to work on all windows platforms that I've tested it out on and solves all my requirements.

Comment: So you prefer "IExpress" over .NET Core? This is exactly what .NET Core does for you...

Comment: My application is 2MB in size when built. Using IExpress actually reduces that to 1.7MB. I tried with .NET Core and it was 60MB though it did solve my requirements